# Unable to open 'start.S': Unable to read file '/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.26/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S'

Tags: opensuse, c++, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up and debugging a c++ program on opensuse system in VS Code.

The debugger is working properly without any issues.

But I get an error pop up saying `Unable to open 'start.S': Unable to read file '/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.26/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.26/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S').`.

Screenshot is -

[image]

My OS information is -

```
    $ lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
    Distributor ID: openSUSE
    Description:    openSUSE Leap 15.1
    Release:        15.1
    Codename:       n/a
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your *launch.json* configuration. I need to set the `stopAtEntry` to false in my case to overcome this issue.